# 1x1 Android Widget shows as 2x2 widget on WXGA720 screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a 1x1 Android widget.  I have designed images for each screen density as follows:

```
ldpi  (120 DPI) = 72 * (120 / 160) == 54 x 54 pixels
mdpi  (160 DPI) = 72 * (160 / 160) == 72 x 72 pixels
hdpi  (240 DPI) = 72 * (240 / 160) == 108 x 108 pixels
xhdpi (320 DPI) = 72 * (320 / 160) == 144 x 144 pixels
```

My widget specification:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minWidth="72dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget">
</appwidget-provider>
```

On WVGA800 screens (hdpi), the widget is 1x1.
On WXGA800 screens (mdpi), the widget is 1x1.
On WXGA720 screens (xhdpi), the widget is **2x2**.

Can someone point me in the direction of what is wrong here?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are saying that your app widget winds up with 288x288 pixels? BTW, `updatePeriodMillis` of `1000` will be ineffective, as the minimum time is 30 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using the updatePeriodMillis actually.  It's just a remnant that will be removed.

My widget is showing as a 2x2 widget, but the image is 144x144.  So, the 2x2 widget has a 1x1 image which appears in the upper left.  The other 3 "cells" are empty, but cannot be occupied.  The widget selection screen (Android 4.0.3) shows it as a 2x2 widget.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before Android 4.0: (n * 74dip) - 2dip
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html

Android 4.0: 70 × n − 30
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy

There's also padding that is automatically added when android:targetSdkVersion="14 or higher" is set.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What's interesting is that I have 2 Android 4.0.3 AVDs, and 1 is showing it as a 1x1 widget, while the other is showing a 2x2 widget.


My AndroidManifest.xml specifices:
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>


My WXGA800 emulator (mdpi) is running Android 4.0.3.  It correctly renders it as a 1x1 widget.  This is also reflected as a 1x1 widget on my Transformer Prime.

My WXGA720 emulator (xhdpi) is also running Android 4.0.3.  It renders it as a 2x2 widget.

Comment: Interesting.  I added a separate widget_info.xml for v14+ to specify 40dip vice 72dip. It now renders correctly on all 4.0.3 test devices.  I did not resize any images, or specify different drawables for v14+.

Comment: Can someone explain how does it make sense? I mean, the widget looks the same on all versions, so how can it take 40dp on Android 4 and 72dp on Android 2.3 ? thanks.

Comment: If you use the widget background assets that are provided on the android website then the padding is included in the png's for the older versions while the newer version of the asset doesn't have padding in it because it's enforced by the homescreen.