# Need help correctly emulating the Samsung Galaxy Nexus with AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, sd-card, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm working to ensure my app is getting tested on ICS properly using the popular Galaxy Nexus as a basis. I'd like to emulate it as faithfully as possible.

I've created an AVD with the following parameters (from config.ini). This was mostly created using the GUI (disk.dataPartition.size is a hand-edited param based on other articles I've read). The memory values may be on the low side but that's not causing a problem for me at the moment.

Since the device had no external sdcard I've said "no" for hw.sdCard, but I'm clearly not seeing anything in the /mnt/scdcard (same as /sdcard) and cannot write to it (remounting isn't the issue AFAIK: that mount doesn't exist at all).

I've tested this a few different ways, including from the adb shell. And, yes, I've searched for an answer here... much of this setup is based on answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8566157/760905), which eventually led me to use disk.dataPartition.size as the equivalent to the command line option (per [this site](http://pickerwengs.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-how-to-set-partition-size-for.html)).

*Edit: if I set hw.sdcard to yes it gives me an sdcard to work with, but I wonder if this is the correct way to go about this (assuming there IS a correct way within this version of the emulator). Plus, this doesn't really help when emulating an ICS device with an actual external sdcard...*

**So (since I don't actually have a Galaxy Nexus to work with):**

- **What would I see for the internal "sdcard" area and mount point**
  (/mnt/sdcard, /sdcard, both, or something else?)
- **What might I do to emulate that "sdcard" correctly** (since it's not really an sdcard per se)?
- **Bonus: What would I also see on a device *with* a physical sdcard?** /Removable (like in Honeycomb)? Something else?

> ```
> abi.type=armeabi-v7a
> disk.dataPartition.size=512
> hw.cpu.arch=arm
> hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
> hw.keyboard.lid=no
> hw.lcd.density=320
> hw.mainKeys=no
> hw.ramSize=512
> hw.sdCard=no
> image.sysdir.1=add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-15\images\armeabi-v7a\
> image.sysdir.2=system-images\android-15\armeabi-v7a\
> sdcard.size=64M
> skin.name=WXGA720
> skin.path=platforms\android-15\skins\WXGA720
> snapshot.present=true
> vm.heapSize=48
> ```

Comment: I think this question is still not answered a year after. Now you can create emulator based on Galaxy Nexus and it is only logical not to set up it with SD card file but this will cause some of the very Google provided sample apps to crash - like Bitmap fun app.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the parameters:

```
Resolution : 720 x 1280
Abstracted LCD density : 316
Max VM application heap size : 48
Device ram size : 1024
```

When creating my AVD I put:

```
Name: Nexus_480x800HDPI
Target: Android 4.0.3 - API Level 15
SD Card - Size: 256 MiB
Snapshot: x Enabled
Skin: x Built-in: WVGA800
```

For me it is just working nicely.

Here you may also find some further info:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations

I hope this help you.

Comment: From what I've read that's not all there is to it (it "works" with hw.sdcard enabled but it's not really accurate). Also, your choice of WVGA800 versus WXGA720 may not be ideal (the latter is supposed to be preferred for this device). Some more discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9282724/760905

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have ram 768MB . Ram greater than that can cause problems on windows environment.