# Android Virtual Device Not Running App

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am brand new to Android app development. I created an app with a text view that says `Hello world!`. I started up the app on a Nexus 7 and Nexus S virtual device. On both devices, it loaded the OS, but the app was no where to be found. It didn't launch and it wasn't in the applications view. Where can I find it?

PS: Sorry for the newbie question ;)

EDIT 1: I tried using `Run > Run` from the toolbar and selecting `Android Application`, and I got this:

```
[2013-06-09 15:20:23 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring build-tool '.DS_Store', not a folder.
[2013-06-09 15:27:45 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring build-tool '.DS_Store', not a folder.
[2013-06-09 15:31:48 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring build-tool '.DS_Store', not a folder.
[2013-06-09 15:34:55 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2013-06-09 15:34:55 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2013-06-09 15:34:55 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-09 15:34:55 - HelloWorld] Performing me.pogostick29.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-09 15:34:56 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nexus7'
[2013-06-09 15:34:56 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus7'
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - Emulator] 2013-06-09 15:35:04.712 emulator64-arm[570:f07] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/XBurn.osax/Contents/MacOS/XBurn:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/XBurn.osax/Contents/MacOS/XBurn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - Emulator]    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/XBurn.osax/Contents/MacOS/XBurn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - Emulator] emulator64-arm: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/XBurn.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-09 15:35:04 - Emulator] 2013-06-09 15:35:04.738 emulator64-arm[570:f07] Loading Maximizer into bundle: (null)
[2013-06-09 15:35:58 - HelloWorld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-09 15:35:58 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-09 15:35:58 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2013-06-09 15:37:16 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2013-06-09 15:37:16 - HelloWorld] Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2013-06-09 15:37:16 - HelloWorld] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2013-06-09 15:37:16 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!
```

Maybe I stopped the emulator too early?

Comment: check the parameters before making the AVD.

see here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427863/need-help-correctly-emulating-the-samsung-galaxy-nexus-with-avd

Comment: Try downloading the complete android eclipse sdk, from `http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html`

Comment: @sarthakmeh I'm using a pre-setup configuration: http://icap.me/i/zjIi0k86zn.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google’s Nexus One is a powerful phone with the latest Android release. Being a device originally sold directly by Google, this phone seems to get updates the soonest. It also has a nice screen and is quite fast, especially with Android 2.2.

The important specs of this device from an Emulator perspective are:

Target platform: Currently Android 2.2

Screen info: Medium sized, high density

No keyboard or DPad
Has track-ball

Therefore, let’s create an AVD configuration called NexusOne:

Within Eclipse, launch the Android SDK and AVD Manager

Select “Virtual Devices” from the left-hand options

Click the “New” button to create a new AVD configuration

Name the AVD: “NexusOne”

Select the Target: “Google APIs API Level 8”

Input the SD Card Size: “4GB”

Input the Skin Details: “WVGA800” (800×480)

Add a Hardware Property for Abstracted LCD Density: “252”

Add another Hardware Property for DPad Support: “No”

Save the AVD

Hope this works.:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it, when I created new virtual device. At first in device log I was chosen ' 5.4" '  but after I choose Nexus 7. I don't know why, but this solved my problem and after running android application it showed in virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

After you start the emulator, you need to select your app project and run it. That will install and launch the app on the emulator.

See here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#RunningOnEmulatorEclipse

Comment: It says something about the Run menu in the menu bar, but my menu bar only has Eclipse while an emulator is running: http://icap.me/i/ajvXbEGi6j.png